# Python not working after installation it only worked once

Tags: python

I downloaded python from the “download page for Continuum Analytics” which after installation was working for the first time, in the end of the installation, the console was getting connected to the kernel, I mistakenly closed the computer. After one hour when I opened the computer again and clicked the “Anaconda3” icon and then “Anaconda3 Navigator” from “all apps” or “spyder(Anaconde3)” icon from the “start menu” of windows, the computer was unable to locate “pythonw.exe” file and the windows was searching for the specified file. When the computer found the file it informed to “fix it” or “delete it” or “cancel”, I chose “fix it” after this when I clicked both “spyder(Anaconde3)” icon in the “start menu” and the “Anaconda3” icon for “Anaconda3 Navigator” in “all apps” both are not working at all. How to fix this problem? I use windows 10.

Comment: I would manually search for the `pythonw.exe` Executable Binary File myself. Find it. Copy its Path. Update all of the Tiles and all of the Icons that should be pointing to it. And test again until all of them are again working.

Comment: I am trying to launch Jupiter notebook from the last day Thursday 09, 2020 atleast and its not getting launched still. How to launch Jupiter notebook the first time?